# Update an input field in the webview from react-native component

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a webview component like this:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
        onMessage(m) {
            //Update an input field in the webview with a custom value
        }
        render(){
            let jsCode = '';
            return (
            <WebView
               ref={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
               injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
               url={this.state.url}
               onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)}
               />
            )
        }
    }
```

The webpage has an input field with an id='inpOne'. onMessage prop is triggered by a button click inside the webpage. How to update the input field with the above id when the onMessage prop is executed?

Stripped most of the code for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably like this.

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
        onMessage(m) {
            const js = `document.getElementById('inpOne').value = ${m};`
            this.webView.injectJavaScript(js);
        }
}
```

Also, check your WebView's ref prop definition. It looks incorrect. Should be `ref={ref => (this.webView = ref)}`

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm able to update the input field now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of how to change HTML inside of WebWiew from React Native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  sendDataFromReactNativeToWebView() {
    let injectedData = `document.getElementById("login_field").value = 'xyz@github.com';`;
    this.webView.injectJavaScript(injectedData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>

        <TouchableHighlight style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'gray', marginTop: 20 }} onPress={() => this.sendDataFromReactNativeToWebView()}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Send Data To WebView from React Native</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/login' }}
          ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}

        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```